# how to parse JSON from URL with basic authentication

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

Is there anyone who can provide me with the different steps I need to parse JSON form an API using basic authentication?

thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by basic authentication? Please can you explain the word "basic"?

Comment: for the moment I use a basic authentication header with plain text username and plain text password.

Comment: there are at least 100 tutorials on the web.  Maybe Google can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSJSONSerialization for that:

[NSJSONSerialization Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Your answer is nearly as detailed as the question is :D